# Expression Blend crashing when editing a Surface2 WPF project

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, pixelsense

I'm building a Surface2 project using WPF. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 and Expression Blend 4 with SketcFlow.

When I open the project in Expression Blend, the program stops responding, after loading up the designer view for the main view xaml. I then get the option to either kill it or debug it in Visual Studio.

In the xaml view, I only have a scatterview, a map control and a tag visualizer.

This is the error I get when debugging this in Visual Studio:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=The scene node must be a composite node to access properties.
  Source=Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface
```

The InvalidOperationException seems to be related accessing the UI thread from any other than it's parent (based on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US/search/default.aspx?query=System.InvalidOperationException) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHINVALIDOPERATION%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)). I do draw some polylines on top of the map layer later on, but that shouldn't break things, as my identical implementation works in a pure non-Surface WPF projet.

My target framework is set to .NET framework 4 on the Visual Studio side. I found this topic: [Using Microsoft Surface controls in Expression Blend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465525/using-microsoft-surface-controls-in-expression-blend), but I'm afraid this doesn't help in my situation. If I create an empty Surface2 WPF project from Visual Studio and then open it in Blend, everything works fine. Also setting the platfrom to Any CPU manually, as instructed in [Trouble when trying to open WPF project in Expression-Blend 4, which was created in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775687/trouble-when-trying-to-open-wpf-project-in-expression-blend-4-which-was-created) didn't work.

Any solutions or ideas for quick workarounds? I was thinking of trying something along the lines of  forcing Blend to open the view xaml in its own editor rather than designer, but couldn't find out how to do that.